# Is it possible to integrate MLS and IDX with ASP.NET MVC 5 website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, idx

I need to integrate IDX MLS into a real estate website. Also I want to know how to implement commercial and residential search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use something like this:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/librets-dotnet/

Typically, a multiple listing service (MLS) uses a technology called RETS to serve listing data. In order to use RETS, you'll need to know the host/login URL the MLS provides and have an account with them for access. Then you can make calls to their RETS/IDX feed using the library above.

Here's the librets documentation: http://www.dis.com/NAR/libRETS_Dev_Guide.html

If I may, please let me provide more detail about these different acronyms:

**MLS - Multiple Listing Service**

- This is a business, not a technology. An MLS provides real estate agents with a means to distribute their listings.

**IDX - Internet Data Exchange**

- An agreement between agents and the MLS they pay to be a part of. IDX is not an actual technology.

**RETS - Real Estate Transaction Standard**

- This is the actual protocol/standard used by (most) multiple listing services. Here's a link to the 1.8 specification (most production RETS servers will support this): https://www.ranww.org/documents/resources/rets_1_8.pdf